# Axios requests front-end instead of server

Tags: laravel, axios, next.js, routes, breeze

I have  used [breeze-next](https://github.com/laravel/breeze-next) as a boilerplate.

User register and login work perfectly but when I create a custom hook to interact with the server, Axios sends requests to front-end address, instead of the server.

I have declared the server address in `.env` file:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

Axios configuration:

```
import Axios from 'axios'

const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,
    headers: {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
})

export default axios
```

My custom hook:

```
export const useAccount = () => {
    const csrf = () => axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')

    const {data: user, error, mutate} = useSWR('/api/user', () =>
        axios
            .get('/api/user')
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status !== 409) throw error

                router.push('/verify-email')
            }),
    )

    const start = async ({setErrors, setStatus, ...props}) => {
        await csrf() // <-- Fails Here

        axios.post('/user/account/start', props)
            .then(() => mutate())
            .catch(error => {
                setErrors(Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat())
            })
    }

    return {
        start
    }
}
```

When axios sends a get request it sends the request to `http://localhost:3000/sanctum/csrf-cookie` which is the front-end address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with wrong import.

I didn't pay attention to what file is IDE importing as axios into account Hook.

It was like this:

```
import axios from "axios"
```

So I changed it to:

```
import axios from "@/lib/axios"
```